# Android: getfromLocationName() returns size 0 in Address List

Tags: java, android, dictionary, location, geocoding

I have a database of locations. When I try to convert them into coordinates so I can place them on a map I get errors. My addresslist of type address has a size zero. I researched the topic. All my manifest permissions are correct. My phone is connected to the internet. I have rebooted my phone. I know there is an google issue and the solutions dont help.  The locations are accurate. Please help.

Here is error message : 
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

```
private void setUpMap()  {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Cursor c  = db.fetchAllAddresses();
    String place = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<android.location.Address> addresses = new ArrayList();
    try {
       addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(place,1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    android.location.Address add = addresses.get(0);
    double lat = add.getLatitude();
    double lng = add.getLongitude();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)).title("Marker"));


    }
```

**EDIT** this is the fetchAllAddresses()

```
  public Cursor fetchAllAddresses() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[]{ "rowid _id", KEY_NAME,},null, null, null,null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Comment: Please post the `fetchAllAddresses()` function.

Comment: @DanielNugent I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not getting any results in your cursor, and `mCursor.moveToFirst();` is returning false in this case.

Typically you would want to check the result of `mCursor.moveToFirst();`, as if it returns false, you know that you have an empty cursor.

The empty cursor is a separate issue, it's hard to tell why that would happen from this code.

In order to get rid of your `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` when the Cursor is empty, this is one way to fix it:

You can do a check to `getCount()` on your cursor to make sure it's greater than zero.
Also make sure to close the cursor, otherwise you will have a memory leak.

```
private void setUpMap()  {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Cursor c  = db.fetchAllAddresses();

    //check for empty cursor
    if (c.getCount() > 0){
      String place = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
      Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
      List<android.location.Address> addresses = new ArrayList();
      try {
         addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(place,1);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      android.location.Address add = addresses.get(0);
      double lat = add.getLatitude();
      double lng = add.getLongitude();
      mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)).title("Marker"));
    }

    c.close();  //get rid of memory leak!

 }
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I have entered values into my database from one activity and am fetching them in this one. I don't understand why the cursor is showing up as empty. @DanielNugent