# google maps api returns empty result

Tags: android, google-api, location, maps

I am working on an Android app using Google Maps API to return location info as JSON. However, the Google Maps API sometimes returns NO result when I search by latitude and longitude. To ensure I have not done something wrong I searched for the city "idhna" like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=idhna&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

it returns

```json
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Idhna",
               "short_name" : "Idhna",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Idhna",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 31.557252,
               "lng" : 34.979243
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 31.5667594,
                  "lng" : 34.9952504
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 31.5477436,
                  "lng" : 34.9632356
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJjfxiM8TuAhURpQKxXGq5lDo",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

but when I copy the latitude and longitude from the result and try to search

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=31.557252,34.979243&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

the result was

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a limitation of the data that this API has access to, and it's basically hit or miss whether you get data for coordinates.

Testing Sumaya, it shows results:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sumaya

However, the situation is the same as the url in your question, it shows no results for the lat/lon:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=31.523946,34.968806

Just as a test, I tried the nearby city Beit Guvrin that is over the border:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=BeitGuvrin

Which returned coordinates:

```json
"location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 32.1298801302915,
                  "lng" : 34.8555745
               },
```

Which returns valid results from the lat/lon:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=32.1298801302915,34.8555745

```json
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "3-41",
               "short_name" : "3-41",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "HaNevi'im Street",
               "short_name" : "HaNevi'im St",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Ramat Hasharon",
               "short_name" : "Ramat Hasharon",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Tel Aviv District",
               "short_name" : "Tel Aviv District",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Israel",
               "short_name" : "IL",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "HaNevi'im St 3-41, Ramat Hasharon, Israel",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 32.130616,
                  "lng" : 34.855772
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.129476,
                  "lng" : 34.853687
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.1297776,
               "lng" : 34.8554613
            },
            "location_type" : "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 32.1313949802915,
                  "lng" : 34.8560784802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.1286970197085,
                  "lng" : 34.8533805197085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "EjLXlNeg15HXmdeQ15nXnSAzLTQxLCDXqNee16og15TXqdeo15XXnywg15nXqdeo15DXnA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Ramat Hasharon",
               "short_name" : "Ramat Hasharon",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Tel Aviv District",
               "short_name" : "Tel Aviv District",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Israel",
               "short_name" : "IL",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Ramat Hasharon, Israel",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 32.158889,
                  "lng" : 34.86803
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.11189,
                  "lng" : 34.795732
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.137793,
               "lng" : 34.840278
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 32.158889,
                  "lng" : 34.86803
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.11189,
                  "lng" : 34.795732
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJdWZI5UtIHRUREKFBBFqVWY0",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Ezor Tel Aviv",
               "short_name" : "Ezor Tel Aviv",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Israel",
               "short_name" : "IL",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Ezor Tel Aviv, Israel",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 32.2021482,
                  "lng" : 34.86803
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.0292531,
                  "lng" : 34.7425159
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.1128462,
               "lng" : 34.8072165
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 32.2021482,
                  "lng" : 34.86803
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.0292531,
                  "lng" : 34.7425159
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJFYqCjvhIHRURfMkU1A0mkV0",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Tel Aviv District",
               "short_name" : "Tel Aviv District",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Israel",
               "short_name" : "IL",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Tel Aviv District, Israel",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 32.202148,
                  "lng" : 34.8756378
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.0165529,
                  "lng" : 34.7425159
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 32.0929075,
               "lng" : 34.8072165
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 32.202148,
                  "lng" : 34.8756378
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 32.0165529,
                  "lng" : 34.7425159
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJsTJP_rZLHRURQNXiBl_Sf9s",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Israel",
               "short_name" : "IL",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Israel",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.33280500000001,
                  "lng" : 35.896244
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 29.4906463,
                  "lng" : 34.2673871
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 31.046051,
               "lng" : 34.851612
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 33.33280500000001,
                  "lng" : 35.896244
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 29.4906463,
                  "lng" : 34.2673871
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJi8mnMiRJABURuiw1EyBCa2o",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I also tested Keidar, and it successfully shows results from the coordinates returned from the address query.

So, it's basically hit or miss, depending on how much data the API has for a given location.

Comment: i tried some apps from google play to test if they can get "adhna" location and they worked well ... so i wonder if there's any other API's i can use to solve this issue.

Comment: @user1814596 You can try the Geocoder API: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html   Example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463160/android-getfromlocationname-returns-size-0-in-address-list/29463865#29463865  And another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521933/how-to-get-latitude-longitude-from-more-than-500-addresses